# Eclipse created app won't run in Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and Android programming and trying to teach myself how to create android apps.The problem is apps won't run in emulator.

1. I have installed Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2.
2. I have installed Android SDk and AVD
3. I have created "HelloWorld" app from Eclipse.
4. Press F11 to run "HelloWorld.
5. Mesasge occurs : "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured."
6. No Android emulator is running.
7. Check on android sdk directory, adb.exe is there.
8. Press F11 again,
9. Android emulator started but "HelloWorld" app is not running
10. No "HelloWorld" app in app manager either.
11. I have delete R.java and run again, result is the same (no "HelloWorld" app running).
12. I have killed adb.exe process and run again, result is the same (no "HelloWorld" app running).

## Below is code from main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first Android Application" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="And this is a clickable button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

=====================================================================

please advice how to remedy this.

Additional info:
I have download all packages (+extras) and created the Virtual Device.
[image: Virtual Devices]

Message from Console
[image: Message from console]

Is there something missing?

There is a exclamation mark on line 15 & 20 (indicated in red box) does this cause the problem?
[image: error in code]

---

Dear All,

Thanks for advice.
After going through the forum, it seems that Android doesn't work well with 64bit application/OS (but some claimed it can work).
I am using Win7 64bit + Eclipse 64bits.
I am sorry that this information is not provided in the first place, maybe things could be resolve faster.

At the moment, the problem is not solved, I just create a virtual PC (in XP mode) and run everything in 32bit. So far everythings works fine.

Special thanks to AndroDev for continuous help in this problem.

---

Comment: Did you restart eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

In your steps you haven't mentioned creating an AVD. you need to create an emulator device before running the app.

Also you need to kill adb and restart it again keeping eclipse closed

```
 1. Go to the Android SDK tools directory in Command Prompt
 2. type adb kill-server
 3. then type adb start-server
 4. No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.
```

Now you can start Eclipse again.
this works normally.

Answer (score 1):

in your eclipse there is a icon for Android VDM. Just click on that icon. After that click on new button. Give the name -->> select the target -->> click on create AVD. after the run your project as Android Application.
may [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have created AVD required to run your app, follow below steps:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Kill adb through command line with command `adb kill-server`
3. Now start task manager and kill adb process also from there if running from the process tab
4. Now start your adb again from command line with `adb start-server`
5. Now start your Eclipse again and run your application

I have faced the same issue many times and followed above steps to overcome that. Hope this will also work for you.

Comment: Hi AndroDev (and Anurag), I have done as per your procedure but result is the same. I can see that the adb.exe is kill from task manager. When reach step 5,  I can see adb.exe started but eclipse error message "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured." when F11 is pressed again (without restart Eclipse) everything runs fine except "helloworld" app is not started in emulator.

Comment: ok. What you can try once is install your app to emulator with adb e.g. using adb install command and check whether your application runs or not.

Comment: Hi AndroDev, Have problem install HelloWorld app with adb command. Try to start emulator but command not recognized (I believe due to many files is shifted to C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools. Try to clear this by assigning the path in Environment Variable but can't work, have to copy all file to C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools. Managed to start emulator and try to install app but "error : device not found".

Comment: first you have to go to C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools in command line (if you have not set your path variable) and then try with installing with command adb install command. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the 'Extras' packages from SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the packages should be perfectly installed and Create AVD from the AVD and SDK manager and start the AVD emulator..You work is done buddy.I hope plugins are perfectly installed...

Comment: Hi Mainank, thanks for advice. I am not sure the installation is perfect or not but I have done the installation twice following the beginner's guide and there is no error. Is there a way to check?